# Android Studio font is cut after trying KDE

Tags: unity, kubuntu, kde, fonts, android-studio

I've recently tried KDE Plasma (kubuntu-desktop) before uninstalling it and going back to Unity.

Now when I open Android Studio the font is cut at the end of the line in the project overview. See image below:

[image: Image showing the issue]

If I change the font used by Android Studio this doesn't happen (it's not reccomended to change it).

Before trying KDE this didn't happen at all.

Android Studio 2.2.1
Build #AI-145.3330264, built on October 6, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b03 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

What can it be?
Thank you.

Comment: That's why I always say there's no safe way to remove a DE. DEs are always a complex fabric made of several inter-operating parts that often cannot be removed without consequences.

Comment: what is the content of `~/.gtkrc-2.0`?

Comment: That's it @Anwar, an include of the /usr/share one and bunch of KDE stuff (NATO font and other things)... I just deleted the file, logged out and in and the problem is gone! Write the answer I'll mark it as accepted! Thank you sir / madame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KDE creates a file with name `.gtkrc-2.0` in your home directory hard-coding the fonts and other theme elements. The problem is, GTK uses this file and anything specified here will override any other values.

So, removing this file if you're not using KDE is a required fix for other sessions installed side-by-side with it.

Remove it with this command

```
rm ~/.gtkrc-2.0
```